# How do I get a similar scrolling effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If you go to this site: http://pixelpointpos.com/

You will see a little animation, movement on some objects as you scroll past. I am looking to achieve a similar effect where if I am to scroll past or to a section, the section image header will animate a lock opening.

As an example say this image would be used: https://www.dnnsoftware.com/portals/0/Images/DNN/login.png

and I would have a different one where the lock is opened. How would I go about animating the images so that upon scrolling to the section the image would ease into the opened lock?

Sorry If I'm not giving enough information, I just don't know how to go about searching for a solution.

Comment: have you ever heard of parrallax effect??if no,then google it,you will get it.Its just parrallax effect..

Comment: I can't fully answer your question as it would take too much time, but the effect you want is called a "Parralax" . There is plenty of information about this and you might want to consider to combine it with a bootstrap 3 like framework.

Answer (score -1):

You can give a parallax Scroll Effect.
Here is a simple tutorial for it here-
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D75WTf_Y738

Answer (score -1):

For getting this type of scrolling effect you have to study about parallax scrolling.

you can refer this link.
http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/create-scrolling-parallax-website/